# Check if Child node exists and get parent node in xml

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I have loaded a xml file and I want a specific node when a child node exists.

For example: if the supplierItem->supplier->id is "0101" I want to get the stock "1" out of this specific supplierItem. So I need the parent stock node of the specific supplier id.

My xml looks something like this

```
<product>
     <supplierItem>
        <id>0001</id>
        <supplier>
           <id>0101</id>
           <name>Company_1</name>
        </supplier>
        <supplierItemId>Product_1_ID</supplierItemId>
        <productName>Product_1</productName>
        <stock>1</stock>
     </supplierItem>
        <id>0002</id>
        <supplier>
           <id>0202</id>
           <name>Company_2</name>
        </supplier>
        <supplierItemId>Product_1_ID</supplierItemId>
        <productName>Product_1</productName>
        <stock>2</stock>
     </supplierItem>
        <id>0003</id>
        <supplier>
           <id>0303</id>
           <name>Company_3</name>
        </supplier>
        <supplierItemId>Product_1_ID</supplierItemId>
        <productName>Product_1</productName>
        <stock>3</stock>
     </supplierItem>
 </product>
```

My first attemp were:

```
 $stocks = $xml->xpath("/product/supplierItem");
    foreach ($stocks as $stock)
    {
         echo($stock);   // get all stocks
    }
```

Any idea? I stuck with it...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up about Xpath. It can do that easily and a lot more:

Fetch `supplierItem` nodes...

`/product/supplierItem`

... With a child node `id` ...

`/product/supplierItem[id]`

... that equals '0101' ...

`/product/supplierItem[id = "0101"]`

... and fetch the `stock` element node from it:

`/product/supplierItem[id = "0101"]/stock`

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` can only return arrays of nodes, but Xpath itselfs allows even to fetch the value directly. In PHP that is possible with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`:

```
$stock = $domXpath->evaluate('string(/product/supplierItem[id = "0101"]/stock)')
```

Comment: nice answer, to include the `SimpleXML` code: `$stock = $xml->xpath("/product/supplierItem[id = '0101']/stock")[0];`

Comment: Accessing the node directly can result in a PHP error message, if no node is found (and the array is empty). For stable source code you would need to validate that you got a node before accessing it. Like using foreach().